# How to convert np array to StringIO

Tags: python, streaming

I ran into a problem while trying to stream images over a local network. On the system with the camera I can see the images perfectly fine and I can establish a socket between the two computers. I want to send the data as a `StringIO` to attach the size of the current image in the String. 
However my computer tells me, it cannot convert a `np array`  to a `str` .
Instead I sent it as a `BytesIO` , but the client cannot reconvert this data.

Is there a way to send the iages as a `StringIO` or to reconvert the `BytesIO`?

Comment: you have to send image as string or bytes, and use `StringIO` or `BytesIO` only in client to receive it and use it to display (without saving on disk). If you need help then show code. BTW: if you really want to use StringIO then you have to get string from it - using `read()` - and send this string, not StringIO.

Comment: BTW. numpy array has `tostring()` and `tobytes()` which you have to use it create string and send it. And client can use `numpy.fromstring()` to convert this string to array again. And later you may need `StringIO` only when functions need file-like object to display image.

Comment: BTW: on GitHub I have examples which get image from camera using `cv2` and use socket to send it to client. I don't need `StringIO` for this but only `pickle` - this way client know how many data it has to receive and I don't have to send this information before image. https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2/socket-send-image

Comment: BTW: sockets sends only bytes and usually server has to `encode()` string to bytes before sending, and client has to `decode()` bytes to string after receiving. And you don't have to send size and image in one string in one `send()`. You can first `send()` only size, and later `send()` data because socket doesn't care how you send it. Socket can send it partially even if you create one string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to encode correctly, as furas pointed out. I had to add the size as a header via `header = '{0}:'.format(packet_size)` ,  `header = bytes(header.encode())` and `out += header`. 
I modeled my approach after this project: https://github.com/sabjorn/NumpySocket

furas's way should work as well, but my approach was closer to the previously mentioned project.